# Displaying xticks using subplot Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm attempting to plot a few subplots. The issue that I'm running into is in labeling the x-axis for each plot since they're all different.

The variables `relHazardRate` and `relHazardFICO` are dataframes of size `50 X 2`

I attempting to plot the below I'm unable to show the x-axis tick marks (i.e. `relHazardRate` is a variable ranging from 3% to 6%, and `relHazardFICO` is a variable ranging from 300-850. Each figure in the subplot will have its own x-axis/ticker (there are 8 such plots) and I have provided my logic for 2 as shown below.

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4), (ax5, ax6), (ax7, ax8)) = plt.subplots(4, 2,figsize=(12,8))

ax1.plot(relHazardRate['orig_coupon'],relHazardRate['Hazard Multiplier']); 
ax1.title.set_text('Original Interest Rate'); 
ax1.set_xticks(range(len(relHazardRate['orig_coupon'])));
ax1.set_xticklabels(relHazardRate['orig_coupon'].to_list())

ax2.plot(relHazardFICO['orig_FICO'],relHazardFICO['Hazard Multiplier'], 'tab:orange');
ax2.title.set_text('Original FICO');
ax2.set_xticks(range(len(relHazardRate['orig_FICO'])));     
ax2.set_xticklabels(relHazardRate['orig_FICO'].to_list())

ax.3 through ax.8 follow a similar decleration as the described above

for ax in fig.get_axes():
    ax.label_outer()
```

The subplot that I get is as follows, I want to label each plot with its own x-axis, as shown this is not happening.

[image]

Comment: Not sure how many more ways to say this... I want to display the x-axis label for every chart, where the x-axis for each chart is different from one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the lines with `label_outer`.

From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.SubplotBase.html#matplotlib.axes.SubplotBase.label_outer):

> `label_outer()`
>
> Only show "outer" labels and tick labels.
>
> x-labels are only kept for subplots on the last row; y-labels only for subplots on the first column

Clearly this is what is causing the behaviour you see in your plot